# Sed - Remove an array element from JSON string

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I have a JSON string as file in single line and there are no spaces between elements. This is how the JSON looks like.

```
{"data":[{"ids":[{"index":"01","type":"02","id":"XYZ12345"}],"scores":[{"name":"STKOVERFLOW","cardName":"08","cardVersion":"10","date":"10062019","score":"00730","reasons":[{"code":"X2345","value":"01"}]}],"telephones":[{"index":"01","number":"9841234567","extension":"4424386","type":"01"}]}]}
```

I have to remove the scores array from the JSON tree.

The idea I had is to remove the `reasons` array first and then remove the `scores` array

I tried few approaches but it does not work. Any help is appreciated.

```
 sed 's/\,\"reasons.*\]//' < input.json      #This removes "]" till the last array present in the json.

sed 's/\,\"reasons.*?\]//' < input.json      #This does not remove any characters in the input

sed 's/\,\"reasons(.*?)\]//' < input.json    #This does not remove any characters in the input
```

I want to achieve this using `sed` as other tools are not available in the organization now.

Your help is appreciated. Thank you !!

Answer (score 2):

Use `jq` to manipulate JSON in scripts (Or another tool that understands the data format), not `sed` or anything else that depends on regular expressions.

```sh
jq -c 'del(.data[0].scores)' input.json > output.json
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer !!   jq is not available in the system and its a tedious process to get jq installed. Any suggestion to achieve this using sed

Comment: @Parthiban Go through the tedious process. Trying to use a tool that doesn't understand JSON to manipulate JSON is like using a screwdriver to cut a sheet of plywood. Completely wrong thing for the job.

Comment: A perl or python script is another option; both come with JSON parsers in their standard libraries.

Comment: Can you add the python script to achieve this?